# Api Gateway Step Functions integration - xml payload problem

Tags: xml, aws-api-gateway, integration, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm a bit struggling with Api Gateway Step Functions integration.
This snippet of my integration:

```js
export const integration = (stateMachineArn: string, accessRole: Role): AwsIntegration =>
  new AwsIntegration({
    service: 'states',
    integrationHttpMethod: 'POST',
    action: 'StartExecution',
    options: {
      credentialsRole: accessRole,
      requestTemplates: {
        'application/xml': JSON.stringify({
          stateMachineArn,
          input: JSON.stringify({
            requestId: '$context.requestId',
            xml: '$input.body',
          }),
        }),
      },
      integrationResponses: [
        {
          statusCode: '200',
          responseTemplates: {
            'application/xml': `
            <ID>$context.requestId</ID>
          `,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

API Gateway exposes POST endpoint which consumes application/xml content type. I need to pass it to step functions, but exactly this line does not work:

```
xml: '$input.body',
```

I see in API Gateway logs that the content is properly recognized:

```
(0dc586c4-a266-48d6-9df7-00793c068230) Endpoint request body after transformations: 
{
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:9999999999999:stateMachine:my-best-state-machine",
    "input": "{\"requestId\":\"0dc586c4-a266-48d6-9df7-00793c068230\",\"xml\":\"\\\"<note>\n<to>Tove</to>\n<from>Jani</from>\n<heading>Reminder</heading>\n<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n</note>\\\"\"}"
}
```

But I'm getting 400 when passing to step functions state machine.

Is this a matter of xml characters? Shouldn't I convert or transform it somehow to successfully pass it to underlaying integration?

According to the official docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
it should just return raw request payload as string. Not sure what to do more here. Anyone can help?

Comment: HTTP Request/Response the Content Type must match the contents.  You cannot send JSON when the type is Xml.  The error 400 is because the server is expecting one type of body (contents) and you are sending a different type.  In many cases the body is serialized and the server has to deserialize you the same method that the client used.